# Recursion working in Python but not in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, recursion

I'm new to Python, and for one of my first projects, I made a script for solving a given [Sudoku puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku).
My script uses recursion to solve the puzzle. I tried to "translate" it to JavaScript to implement it on a website, but that didn't work.
In the following you can find my Python and JS code.

**Python**

```
import numpy as np
sudoku = [[1,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,0,5,1,4,0,9,0],
            [0,3,0,9,0,5,0,8,0],
            [0,2,7,8,0,1,5,6,0],
            [0,5,0,4,0,2,0,7,0],
            [0,0,0,7,4,9,0,3,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
            [4,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

def isPossible(x,y,n):
    global sudoku
    for row in range(9):
        if sudoku[row][x] == n:
            return False
    for col in range(9):
        if sudoku[y][col] == n:
            return False
    x0 = (x//3)*3
    y0 = (y//3)*3
    for a in range(3):
        for b in range(3):
            if sudoku[y0+a][x0+b] == n:
                return False
    return True

def solve():
    global sudoku
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if sudoku[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if isPossible(x,y,n):
                        sudoku[y][x] = n
                        solve()
                        sudoku[y][x] = 0
                return
    print(np.matrix(sudoku))

solve() #prints the solved puzzle
```

**JS**

```
let grid = [[1,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,5,1,4,0,9,0],
    [0,3,0,9,0,5,0,8,0],
    [0,2,7,8,0,1,5,6,0],
    [0,5,0,4,0,2,0,7,0],
    [0,0,0,7,4,9,0,3,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
    [4,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

function isPossible(x,y,n){
    for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        if(grid[y][i] === n){
            return false;
        }
        if(grid[i][x] === n){
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(grid[Math.floor(y/3)*3+i][Math.floor(x/3)*3+j] === n){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function solve() {
    for(let y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        for(let x = 0; x < 9; x++){
            if(grid[y][x] === 0){
                for(let n = 1; n < 10; n++){
                    if(isPossible(x, y, n)){
                        grid[y][x] = n;
                        solve();
                        grid[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return grid;
}

/*
* prints 'undefined' when there are only a few blanks (0's) in the array
* and is loading way longer than python if there are many blanks like in the example
* array above
*/
console.log(solve());
```

Do Python and JS treat the return statement differently? Is something else the problem? Thank you for help!

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? what did it do that you didn't expect?

Comment: What happens if you change the last line to two lines: `solve();` and `console.log(grid)`?

Comment: oh sorry, i stated the problem in a comment above the outprinting in the code, not the most obvious spot to explain it i guess. So, javascript just prints out undefined

Comment: changing the outprint into two lines doesnt change anything. And 'undefined' is printed out because of the inner return statement, I could change it into "return "a string"" and it would return "a string".

Comment: The javascript function has a bare `return;` statement.  if that line is executed, the function will return nothing, which seems to match the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: But the bare return statement is there to "fall back" to the previous solve()-function when no digit from 1 to 9 is possible

Comment: `return` isn't acting differently.  You're using a `return` in the JS that you don't use in the Python.  If you replaced `return grid` with `console.log(grid)`, you would get similar behavior.  Other than that, this is a faithful reconstruction of the Python, although it would be nicer if you wrote a `range` helper function to be used with `for..of`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a fairly faithful translation of the Python, except for one thing.  You change Python's `print` call into a `return grid` statement.  The problem is that the way your loops are structured, we are never actually returning the completed grid, in either Python or JS.  If you replace that line with `console.log(grid)`, you will print the return just as does the Python code.

I would probably code a Sudoku solver quite differently, without depending upon a global grid, passing it through the functions and returning something.  But if you want as faithful a translation of the Python as possible, I would write a `range` helper function to use with `for-of`.  (I would also write a simple formatting function to replace `np.matrix`.)  This would do it:

```js
const range = (min, max) => 
  max == undefined ? range (0, min) : [...Array(max - min)].map((_, i) => i + min)

const matrix = (grid) =>
  grid .map (row => row .join (' ')) .join ('\n')

function isPossible (x, y, n) {
  for (let row of range (9)) {
    if (sudoku [y] [row] === n) {
      return false
    }
  }
  for (let col of range (9)) {
    if (sudoku [col] [x] === n) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  let x0 = Math.floor (x / 3) * 3
  let y0 = Math.floor (y / 3) * 3
  for (let a of range (3)) {
    for (let b of range (3)) {
      if (sudoku [y0 + a] [x0 + b] === n) {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return true
}

function solve() {
  for (let y of range (9)) {
    for (let x of range (9)){
      if (sudoku [y] [x] === 0){
        for (let n of range (1, 10)) {
          if (isPossible (x, y, n)) {
            sudoku [y] [x] = n
            solve ()
            sudoku [y] [x] = 0
          }
        }
        return
      }
    }
  }
  //************************************************************
  console .log (matrix (sudoku)); // This is the important change!
  //************************************************************
}

let sudoku = [
  [1,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
  [0,0,0,5,1,4,0,9,0],
  [0,3,0,9,0,5,0,8,0],
  [0,2,7,8,0,1,5,6,0],
  [0,5,0,4,0,2,0,7,0],
  [0,0,0,7,4,9,0,3,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
  [4,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]


solve()
```

(No critique is intended of your changes to `isPossible`; they should work fine.  This simply attempts to be as close to the Python as the differing syntaxes allow.)

But again, yours will print the result with only that single change.

So, no it has nothing to do with how Python and JS `return` works.  It's that you changed a `print` into a `return`.

Comment: surprisingly succinct brute force solver. i wasn't thinking about sodoku when i saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65347499/633183) but there is definitely a relation. wow the set theory bells are really ringing in my head today. time to cook up some new techniques...

Comment: @Thankyou: I would distinguish this as a backtracking solution rather than a brute-force solver.  I'm thinking about what a functional version might look like, and I might be forced into CPS even after my comments the other day on another JS recursion question.

Comment: i was under the impression backtracking solutions include some way to prune large possibility spaces. i'm very slow to wrap my head around imperative `for` loops used in combination with recursion, so maybe it's just a matter of me not being able to see it. I sparked a bit of a debate in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442925/633183) by saying the two don't mix. would love to see a functional solution to this sudoku problem.

Comment: @Thankyou: There is much pruning going on.  With 52 open cells to fill in in the sample, and 9 possibilities for each, the universe has 9^52 possibilities (4.17e49), which we couldn't search sub-second.  We prune with `isPossible`.  I too was pleasantly surprised by the speed, but I've never tried to code one myself (except for the trivial conversion above.)  I hope to find time soon to search for an effective and efficient FP version.

Answer (score 0):

Not really solved, but I found a solution to the undefined problem:

As some others have mentioned, it is the bare return: If you replace it with a return grid it will give you the array.

The next problem is, that the grid doesn't get solved correctly

I tried commenting out your grid[y][x] = 0, which gave me better results but still not a solved grid:

with grid[y][x] = 0:

```
[
[1,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,5,1,4,0,9,0],
[0,3,0,9,0,5,0,8,0],
[0,2,7,8,0,1,5,6,0],
[0,5,0,4,0,2,0,7,0],
[0,0,0,7,4,9,0,3,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
[4,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

without grid[y][x] = 0:

```
[
[1,7,2,3,9,8,4,5,6],
[5,4,9,2,6,7,8,1,3],
[3,6,8,5,1,4,2,9,7],
[6,3,4,9,7,5,1,8,2],
[9,2,7,8,3,1,5,6,4],
[8,5,1,4,0,2,0,7,0],
[0,0,0,7,4,9,0,3,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
[4,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

I also tried giving the grid as function param through all the functions like solve(grid_to_solve), but that didn't change things for me

I hope this will get you on the right track though