# Recursion optimization

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to find a certain path through my 2d array

My array could look like this:

```
temp = [
    ["placeholder", 2, 0],
    ["placeholder", 1, 7, 3],
    ["placeholder", 4, 5, 8],
    ["placeholder", 6, 3, 5, 2],
    ["placeholder", 7],
    ["placeholder", 3, 0],
]
```

The inner arrays contain a placeholder followed by a variable amount of integers. These integers range in value between 0-19 (0 and 19 both included)

I wanna find a path from top to bottom through these inner arrays where no number is used more than once.

At `temp[0]` i can choose my 1st value either `2` or `0`
At `temp[1]` i can choose my 2nd value either `1`, `7` or `3`
At `temp[2]` i can choose my 3rd value either `4`, `5` or `8`
At `temp[3]` i can choose my 4th value either `6`, `3`, `5` or `2`
Notice at this step I cannot pick `2` if I had already chosen `2` in the 1st step
I cannot pick `3` if I had already chosen `3` in the 2nd step
I cannot pick `5` if I had already chosen `5` in the 3rd step
etc.

These are some legal paths:

- 2-1-4-6-7-3
- 0-1-4-5-7-3

These are some illegal paths:

- 2-1-4-2-7-3 (2 is touched twice)
- 0-1-4-5-7-0 (0 is touched twice)

I want my function to output a completely legal path.
I just want my function to return false if no path is found.
I've tried to write my own recursive solution to this problem, which I think is working, but suffers from heavy inefficiency and therefore takes literal ages to complete.
The size of my intended array is more like 20 x 1..20

So far my code looks like this (written in Python 3) (and with a temp array):

```py
temp= [
    ["placeholder", 7, 3],
    ["placeholder", 3, 3],
    ["placeholder", 4, 3],
    ["placeholder", 3, 8],
    ["placeholder", 1, 3],
]

def findpath(array, path = []):
    
    if path and path.count(path[-1]) > 1:
        return False

    if len(path) == len(array):
        print(path)
        return True
    
    routes = array[len(path)][1:]

    for route in routes:
        path.append(route)
        if findpath(array, path):
            return True
        path.pop(-1)

findpath(temp)
```

This code prints: `[7, 3, 4, 8, 1]`

This approach is brute-forcing through every possibility until a solution is reached. In a worst-case scenario, my `temp` array would contain 20 arrays all containing 20 values each, that would make for 20! possible solutions, or in other words 2.432.902.008.176.640.000 possible paths. Let's exaggerate and say my pc takes 1 ms to process a single iteration of this function. My math could be wrong but that would mean this process could take 77,146,816.6 years to complete (not accounting for leap years), and imma be honest, I don't got this kinda time.

There must be a smarter way to approach this problem.
One thing I've noticed is that if the function encounters an inner array at step e.g. 15, containing only a single int e.g. `2`, then the function will try adjusting its latest picks (first step 14 then step 13) one at a time, without realizing it has already picked `2` at step 2. In this situation by going back to step 2 and change the value from `2` to something else will save a f*** ton of iteration. The only problem is I have no idea how to implement this, nor any idea how to optimize this further.

Here is a real example array (not sure if it contains a solution)

```py
temp = [
['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 11, 15, 16], 
['placeholder', 11, 14, 15, 16], 
['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 11, 15], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 15], 
['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
['placeholder', 2, 11, 14, 15, 16], 
['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
]
```

Hope you can help me learn <3

Comment: Can you clarify what is the valid "move" from one row to next row, and column? And if there is no valid path, what  is the output?

Comment: I've edited the post a bit hopefully this makes more sense  :)

Comment: So the output is what you expect? What is the problem? If efficiency, can you provide a concrete example where this becomes a problem?

Comment: Hey I've changed the post again thanks for the input :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the "backtracking" algorithm? You could study it and apply the same technique here. Just Google the subject.  You will learn more. If still stuck later, you can post follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ill give it a look

Comment: @pluto9800 I made some edits to my post after seeing your real input example. If you have any questions on my post, I'm happy to help :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. ill go through your post now and make sure to let you know if I need further assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**functional heritage**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding mutations like `.append` and `.pop` and other side effects.

Below we use a `set` to efficiently skip invalid combinations and a `tuple` to store the path. A *new* set and tuple are constructed for each recursion -

```py
def traverse(t, s = set(), p = ()):
  if not t:
    yield p
  else:
    [ [_, *values], *more ] = t
    for v in values:
      if v not in s:
        yield from traverse(more, {*s, v}, (*p, v))
```

Using the data in your sample program -

```py
temp = \
  [ ["placeholder", 7, 3]
  , ["placeholder", 3, 3]
  , ["placeholder", 4, 3]
  , ["placeholder", 3, 8]
  , ["placeholder", 1, 3]
  ]

for p in traverse(temp):
  print(p)
```

```py
(7, 3, 4, 8, 1)
(7, 3, 4, 8, 1)
```

And using the data in your original question -

```py
temp = \
  [ ["placeholder", 2, 0]
  , ["placeholder", 1, 7, 3]
  , ["placeholder", 4, 5, 8]
  , ["placeholder", 6, 3, 5, 2]
  , ["placeholder", 7]
  , ["placeholder", 3, 0]
  ]

for p in traverse(temp):
  print(p)
```

```py
(2, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3)
(2, 1, 4, 6, 7, 0)
(2, 1, 4, 3, 7, 0)
(2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 3)
(2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 0)
(2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 3)
(2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 0)
(2, 1, 5, 3, 7, 0)
(2, 1, 8, 6, 7, 3)
(2, 1, 8, 6, 7, 0)
(2, 1, 8, 3, 7, 0)
(2, 1, 8, 5, 7, 3)
(2, 1, 8, 5, 7, 0)
(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 0)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 0)
(2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 0)
(2, 3, 8, 6, 7, 0)
(2, 3, 8, 5, 7, 0)
(0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3)
(0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 3)
(0, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3)
(0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 3)
(0, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3)
(0, 1, 8, 6, 7, 3)
(0, 1, 8, 5, 7, 3)
(0, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3)
```

---

**generators are lazy**

Because we're using a generator, we can stop generating the paths at any time. Perhaps you only want to find the *first* valid path -

```py
def first_valid_path(t):
  for path in traverse(t):
    return path

temp = \
  [ ["placeholder", 2, 0]
  , ["placeholder", 1, 7, 3]
  , ["placeholder", 4, 5, 8]
  , ["placeholder", 6, 3, 5, 2]
  , ["placeholder", 7]
  , ["placeholder", 3, 0]
  ]

print(first_valid_path(temp))
```

```py
(2, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3)
```

---

**optimisation**

One such optimisation we can make is to sort the input array by the number of possibilities, least posibilities first, as these are the most difficult to fulfill -

```py
temp.sort(key=len)
print(temp)
```

```py
[ ['placeholder', 15]
, ['placeholder', 11, 15] 
, ['placeholder', 11, 15, 16] 
, ['placeholder', 11, 14, 15, 16] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 11, 14, 15, 16] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]  
, ['placeholder', 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
, ['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
]
```

I didn't measure it, but a solution is found instantly (less than one second) -

```py
print(first_valid_path(temp))
```

```py
(15, 11, 16, 14, 2, 6, 18, 19, 10, 7, 17, 8, 9, 13, 12, 4, 1, 0, 5, 3)
```

To put the path in correct order, it would need to be un-sorted. There are a number of ways this can be done and I will consider updating the post later with a proposed solution. For now, that is left as an exercise for the reader :D

---

**unsort**

If you made it this far, great! Above I proposed a sorting and unsorting process and below I'll show one such way to handle the unsorting -

```py
def traverse(init):
  def sort(t):
    z = list(enumerate(t))
    z.sort(key=lambda _: len(_[1]))
    return z

  def unsort(p):
    p.sort(key=lambda _: _[0])
    return tuple(v for (_, v) in p)

  def loop(t, s, p):
    if not t:
      yield unsort(p)
    else:
      [ (k, [_, *values]), *more ] = t
      for v in values:
        if v not in s:
          yield from loop(more, {*s, v}, [*p, (k, v)])
  
  yield from loop(sort(init), set(), [])
```

This works by creating an intermediate representation with `sort` -

```py
[ (16, ['placeholder', 15])
, (10, ['placeholder', 11, 15])
, (7, ['placeholder', 11, 15, 16])
, (8, ['placeholder', 11, 14, 15, 16])
, (18, ['placeholder', 2, 11, 14, 15, 16])
, (4, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16])
, (0, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18])
, (3, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19])
, (2, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19])
, (5, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19])
, (1, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (19, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (6, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (14, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (11, ['placeholder', 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (15, ['placeholder', 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (12, ['placeholder', 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (9, ['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (17, ['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
, (13, ['placeholder', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
]
```

The paths are made up of tuples `(sort_key, value)` and `unsort`ed using the `sort_key` -

```py
[(16, 15), (10, 11), (7, 16), (8, 14), (18, 2), (4, 6), (0, 18), (3, 19), (2, 10), (5, 7), (1, 17), (19, 8), (6, 9), (14, 13), (11, 12), (15, 4), (12, 1), (9, 0), (17, 5), (13, 3)]
```

Finally the `sort_key` is removed and only the value path we care about is yielded. Now we can see the path in the correct order. The result is instantly computed (less than one second) -

```py
print(first_valid_path(temp))
```

```py
(18, 17, 10, 19, 6, 7, 9, 16, 14, 0, 11, 12, 1, 3, 13, 4, 15, 5, 2, 8)
```

---

**all valid paths**

Above we use `find_first_path` but our sorting/unsorting technique is also efficient at finding *all* solutions -

```py
for p in traverse(temp):
  print(p)
```

For this particular input, there is only *one* valid path. However this program terminates quickly (less than one second), signalling that all possibilities have been exhausted.

Comment: For small input like the one in post, it works fine. However, for larger 2D array (20x20) as @pluto9800 asked  it seems to take much much longer - 368.528 seconds in my Acer Aspire E15 PC?  Is that expected?

Comment: Daniel, 7 minutes to exhaust _all_ of the solutions or find just the _first_ one? Still it’s an improvement over 77 billion years. One optimisation I thought of but didn’t implement here was 1) sort the input array with fewest possibilities first, as those requirements are harder to fulfill, 2) perform the traversal, 3) unsort the traversed paths to restore to their original order. Post the data you worked with and maybe I’ll take a shot at it later today. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Thank you! @Thank you.  It's indeed significant improvement.  Just wonder is there any room for further performance boost...( since the author post the question for 20x20 array).  Great ideas - will try too.   Thumbs up!

Comment: The `[ [_, *values], *more] = t` line can be optimised as well. Instead of destructuring which creates intermediate values, an index could be used. It adds more conceptual overhead but subtracts space and time from the computational process.

Comment: Daniel, I did a quick test of the sorting theory and it works out for the OP-supplied large data set. The un-sorting step would not be too difficult and does not add any significant time/space requirements for the process. I'll keep cracking away at this as time permits.

Comment: Amazingly fast now!  Congrats!  The unsort will work best - because it keeps the traverse order. Now the time is -  total time: 0.0119.  Suggestions: for the benefit of the author (as general public) - maybe write a elaborated analysis and optimization this  evolves.  Thank you!  @ Thank you.    Great Job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226138/discussion-between-daniel-hao-and-thank-you).