# Recursively Search in Array with a For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion

I know there are better ways to search an array, but I really want to understand how to return when the value is found in a recursive call.  Logging when found isn't a problem, but I can't seem to make this return true when found.

The problem is basic.  Fully search multi-dimensional array for a value and return true if found or false if not found, using a for loop and recursion.  I've tried returning the recursive function and everything else I can think of, but nothing works fully.

```
function lookForKey( arr ){
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if( arr[i] == "key" ){
            console.log( "Key found.");
            return true;
        } else if( Array.isArray( arr[i] ) ){
            lookForKey( arr[i] );
        }
    }

    return false;
}

let arr = [
    ["foo", "bar"],
    ["foo", "bar", "key"]
];

console.log( lookForKey( arr ) );
```

I appreciate any insight on this!

Comment: Your else if does not return.  So if the recursive call returns true/false, then nothing is done with the result from the caller

Comment: Are you _only_ looking for a recursive solution?  There are plenty of ways to do this.

Comment: @jmargolisvt They're not looking for a solution.  They are looking to learn what they are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  I know that's the start.  And now that I think about it, it changes the question entirely.

Returning the recursive call causes the function to return after checking the first array, since it doesn't match any conditional.  I'm just not sure how to make the recursive call continue with the previous for loop after that first call doesn't find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function lookForKey( arr ){
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if( arr[i] == "key" ){
            console.log( "Key found.");
            return true;
        } else if( Array.isArray( arr[i] ) ){
            if (lookForKey(arr[i])) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

let arr = [
    ["foo", "bar"],
    ["foo", "bar", "key"]
];

console.log( lookForKey( arr ) );
```

So two changes.  First, you have to have the return on the recursive call.  However, if the recursive call returns false, you don't want to return immediately from the caller.  You want to continue the loop.  So you can make that a conditional and only return true if the recursive call returns true.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain.  I understand why this works.  I'm still missing something on what, exactly, causes the recursive call to return out of the loop after checking the last item in the first array, rather than continuing to iterate.

Comment: @Mike with your example data, it will return true from the `if` because `key` is the last value in the last sub array.  If it did not exist in any of the sub arrays, all of the for loops would finish without returning and the return false at the bottom would happen.

Comment: Sorry!  I meant prior to adding your conditional, when just returning the recursive call.

`return lookForKey( arr[i] );`

This stops after checking the first array in my example data, rather than moving on to the next array.  I'm not understanding why that would stop.

Comment: If you don't have the conditional on the nested call, it would go into that nested call for the first array.  It would then check the all the elements and see they are not `key`.  The else would not happen because none of the nested array values are arrays themselves, so it would return the false at the bottom of the method, which would return false to the caller.  So at that point the logic has validated that the key is not in the first sub array.  If you immediately returned that false, that would terminate the method and you would not advance to checking the proceeding sub arrays. @Mike

Comment: Question asks to solve the problem recursively and this answer still uses a `for` loop ‍♀️

Comment: @Thankyou The answer addresses the issue asked about.  The goal of the question is to explain why it did not work.  The goal is not to change the question.  You can disagree with the OPs approach, but teaching someone how to do something is not a bad thing.

Comment: @Taplar I don’t completely disagree with you. However if the learner stops at this answer and leaves the `for` loop in place, you only taught them how to recklessly combine a technique from one school of thought with techniques from another school. It’s no longer the proper way to use _either_ technique!

Comment: I disagree that the concept of a `for` loop and the concept of `recursion` are different schools of thought.  You are arguing implementation details, not schools of thought.  @Thankyou  But this is getting conversational.  The OP now has the benefits of seeing this solution and other solutions, to see different points of view.

Comment: @Thank you - The first sentence in my question is, "I know there are better ways to search an array".  I was just trying to make sense of something I encountered in an algorithm exercise that wants both a for loop and recursion.  Thanks to Taplar, I have a much better understanding now.  I do appreciate your answer and expertise on recursion though.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects. `for` is a side effect and is the looping construct used in imperative style. Notice when we use functional style there's no reason to use `for` as recursion *is* the loop.

1. If the input `arr` is empty, there is nothing to search for. Return the base case, `false`
2. (induction) The input `arr` is not empty. If the first element `arr[0]` is an array, recursively `search` the element *or* recursively search the sub-problem, `arr.slice(1)`
3. (induction) The input `arr` is not empty and the first element is not an array. If the first element matches the query, `q`, return true, otherwise recursively search the sub-problem, `arr.slice(1)`

Below we write `search` using the [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) provided above -

```js
function search (arr, q)
{ if (arr.length === 0)
    return false                                         // 1
  else if (Array.isArray(arr[0]))
    return search(arr[0], q) || search(arr.slice(1), q)  // 2
  else
    return arr[0] === q || search(arr.slice(1), q)       // 3
}

const input =
  [ ["foo", "bar"]
  , ["foo", "bar", "key"]
  ]

console.log(search(input, "key"))
console.log(search(input, "bar"))
console.log(search(input, "zzz"))
```

If we're splitting hairs, `if`, `else`, and `return` are also side effects. You can also write `search` as a pure expression -

```js
const search = (arr, q) =>
  arr.length === 0
    ? false                                          // 1
: Array.isArray(arr[0])
    ? search(arr[0], q) || search(arr.slice(1), q)   // 2
: arr[0] === q || search(arr.slice(1), q)            // 3

const input =
  [ ["foo", "bar"]
  , ["foo", "bar", "key"]
  ]

console.log(search(input, "key"))
console.log(search(input, "bar"))
console.log(search(input, "zzz"))
```

And destructuring assignment makes things a little more declarative -

```js
const none =
  Symbol("none")

const search = ([ v = none, ...more ], q) =>
  v === none
    ? false                             // 1
: Array.isArray(v)
    ? search(v, q) || search(more, q)   // 2
: v === q || search(more, q)            // 3

const input =
  [ ["foo", "bar"]
  , ["foo", "bar", "key"]
  ]

console.log(search(input, "key"))
console.log(search(input, "bar"))
console.log(search(input, "zzz"))
```

All variations of `search` above have the same output -

```js
true
true
false
```

---

I sparked some controversy by making some comments about recursion and `for` loops not belonging to the same school of thought. First, here's what `search` could look like *without* recursion -

```js
function search (arr, q)
{ const s = [arr]
  let v
  while(v = s.shift())
    if(Array.isArray(v))
      for (const _ of v)
        s.unshift(_)
    else if (v === q)
      return true
  return false
}

const input =
  [ ["foo", "bar"]
  , ["foo", "bar", "key"]
  ]

console.log(search(input, "key"))
console.log(search(input, "bar"))
console.log(search(input, "zzz"))
```

But that's not to say ideas *cannot* cross schools. Consider this variant that uses `forEach` with recursion and draws upon a [call-with-current-continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) technique, `callcc` below -

```js
const callcc = f =>
{ try { return f(value => { throw {callcc, value} }) }
  catch (e) { if (e.callcc) return e.value; else throw e }
}

function search (arr, q)
{ const loop = (t, exit) =>
    Array.isArray(t)
      ? t.forEach(v => loop(v, exit))
      : t === q && exit(t)
  return callcc(k => loop(arr, k))
}

const input =
  [ ["foo", "bar"]
  , ["foo", "bar", "key"]
  ]

console.log(search(input, "key"))
console.log(search(input, "bar"))
console.log(search(input, "zzz"))
```

Comment: this answer is an art <3, +1

Comment: @thank you While this didn't address my specific question, this is great information and very well constructed.  I'll definitely explore everything you've shared.

Comment: happy to help, Mike. feel free to reach out if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The result comes as false because we are trying to return false from the function. While the for loop is running, the one way to break it when we get the desired result is to use `break`. And we can save the status of find in a variable called `result` which can be returned from the function `lookForKey`

```
function lookForKey( arr ) {
    var result = false;
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if( arr[i] == "key" ){
            result = true;
            break;
        } else if( Array.isArray( arr[i] ) ){
            result = lookForKey( arr[i] );
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

In the above code, instead of returning false from the function, we are returning the `result` variable which contains the actual value of the search. We use `break` statement here to break out from for loop as soon as we get the desired result.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for correcting me. I misunderstood the question and have edited it now. Let me know if you think I understood correctly this time. Pardon me as I am a new contributor.

Answer (score 0):

Asserting a found condition by returning true can be done in a single logical expression that will shortcut as soon as truth is undeniable.

```js
function myFind( haystack, needle ){
    for ( let i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++ ) {
        if ( haystack[i] === needle 
             ||
             ( Array.isArray( haystack[i] ) 
               &&
               myFind( haystack[i], needle )
             )
           ) 
           return true; // return only when found

        // not found, check next array element
    }

    return false;  // not found as any element or in any element
}

let arr = [
    ["foo", "bar"],
    ["foo", "bar", "key"]
];

console.log( myFind( arr, "key" ) );
console.log( myFind( arr, "foo" ) );
console.log( myFind( arr, "xyzzy" ) );
```

Comment: Thanks @richard!  Your explanation really helped as well.