# how can a recursive function operate if it returns to the beginning?

Tags: function, sorting, recursion, mergesort

*I am a novice programmer*

I am looking up into a problem which is using a recursive function. Though I could understand the main point, there is an unclear issue which I could not decipher immediately as I go through the debugging process. I will appreciate your help on my question.

The problem's concept (*merge sorting*) is pretty straight forward, but I am confused with the way a recursive function works in general. Bellow is the program I am dealing with (from Georgia Tech course on Python):

```py
def mergesort(lst):

    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst

    else:

        midpoint = len(lst) // 2
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])

        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:])

        newlist = []
        while len(left) and len(right) > 0:
            if left[0] < right[0]:
                newlist.append(left[0])
            else:
                newlist.append(right[0])
                del right[0]

        newlist.extend(left)
        newlist.extend(right)

        return newlist

print(mergesort([2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 4, 7]))
```

QUESTION: What happens when the program reaches this line `left = mergesort( lst[:midpoint])`?

Based on my understanding, it returns to the first line of the program and comes down again to reach the same line (just like `for` does).

So it keeps returning!!! This, however, makes the program unreadable to me. In general, How the program deals with the recursive function is my main question. I could not understand the way it works.

Comment: Do you know what a function is? Do you know what a function call is?

Comment: Yes I know what a function is. I have problem with tracking the recursion. Is the program automatically storing each step to come back to after each function call?

Comment: I think you should look up some simple examples of recursion to learn how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would happen When the program reaches this line `left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])`? Based on my understanding, it returns to the first line of the program and comes down again to reach the same line...

Each time the program recurs, it calls `mergesort` with a *smaller* list. We call this a "sub-problem" -

```py
def mergesort(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        # ...
    else:
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2           # find midpoint
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])   # solve sub-problem one
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:])  # solve sub-problem two
        # ...
```

For example, if we first call `mergesort` with a 4-element list -

```py
mergesort([5,2,4,7])
```

The input list, `lst`, does not meet the base case, so we move onto the `else` branch -

```py
def mergesort(lst):                       # lst = [5,2,4,7]
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        # ...
    else:
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2          # midpoint = 2
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])  # left = mergesort([5,2])
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:]) # right = mergesort([4,7])
        # ...
```

Notice `mergesort` is called with `[5,2]` and `[4,7]` sub-problems. Let's repeat these steps for the first sub-problem -

```py
left = mergesort([5,2])
```

```py
def mergesort(lst):                       # lst = [5,2]
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        # ...
    else:
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2          # midpoint = 1
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])  # left = mergesort([5])
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:]) # right = mergesort([2])
        # ...
```

> So it keeps returning!!!

Not exactly. When we solve the sub-problems in this step, things looks different. When the input is one element or less, the *base case* is satisfied and the function exits -

```py
left = mergesort([5])
```

```py
def mergesort(lst):     # lst = [5]
    if len(lst) <= 1:   # base case condition satisfied
        return lst      # return [5]
    else:
        ...             # no more recursion
```

Recursion stops for the `left` sub-problem and the answer of `[5]` is returned. The same applies for the `right` sub-problem -

```py
right = mergesort([2])
```

```py
def mergesort(lst):     # lst = [2]
    if len(lst) <= 1:   # base case condition satisfied
        return lst      # return [2]
    else:
        ...             # no more recursion
```

Next we return our first `left` sub-problem -

```py
left = mergesort([5,2])
```

```py
def mergesort(lst):                       # lst = [5,2]
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        # ...
    else:
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2          # midpoint = 1
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])  # left = [5]        <-
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:]) # right = [2]       <-
        # ...
        return newlist                    # newlist = [2,5]
```

You would now repeat these steps for the first `right` sub-problem -

```py
right = mergesort([4,7])
```

```py
def mergesort(lst):                       # lst = [4,7]
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        # ...
    else:
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2          # midpoint = 1
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])  # left = mergesort([4])
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:]) # right = mergesort([7])
        # ...
```

Again, recursion stops as the new `left` and `right` sub-problems are a single-element list, which satisfies the base case -

```py
right = mergesort([4,7])
```

```py
def mergesort(lst):                       # lst = [4,7]
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        # ...
    else:
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2          # midpoint = 1
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])  # left = [4]       <-
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:]) # right = [7]      <-
        # ...
        return newlist                    # newlist = [4,7]
```

And finally the outermost `mergesort` call can return -

```py
mergesort([5,2,4,7])
```

```py
def mergesort(lst):                       # lst = [5,2,4,7]
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        # ...
    else:
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2          # midpoint = 2
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])  # left = [2,5]
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:]) # right = [4,7]
        # ...
        return newlist                    # newlist = [2,4,5,7]
```

```py
# => [2,4,5,7]
```

---

All of that said, recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects. Consider this alternative which lowers the conceptual overhead by clearly separating the program's concerns -

```py
def mergesort(lst):
  def split(lst):
    m = len(lst) // 2
    return (lst[:m], lst[m:])

  def merge(l, r):
    if not l:
      return r
    elif not r:
      return l
    elif l[0] < r[0]:
      return [l[0]] + merge(l[1:], r)
    else:
      return [r[0]] + merge(l, r[1:])

  if len(lst) <= 1:
    return lst
  else:
    (left, right) = split(lst)
    return merge(mergesort(left), mergesort(right))

mergesort([5,2,4,7])
```

```py
# => [2,4,5,7]
```

Comment: Hi Farhad, depending how it is written, a recursive function can evolve a linear iterative process _or_ a tree-like process. The mixing of `for` loops with recursion is typically a recipe for a headache. This [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442925/633183) from last week talks about exactly this. Let me know if you have any follow-up questions :D

Comment: Could you add what would happen if you were to do the other things ("... like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects.")? Could you also clarify what you mean by "functional heritage"?

Answer (score 2):

the answer to your question is: [*copies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613542/849891).

each function is a *recipe* for calculation.

when a function is called, the recipe's *copy* is created. each invocation involves creation of a separate copy. that's how each can operate on its own, and they all are *not* jumbled up together.

*in general,* there is nothing special about a recursive function call. a function call is a function call, no matter what is the function that is called. a function is called, does what it does, and its result is returned to the caller. as for *recursion*, you're not supposed to track it. it does its work on its own. you're supposed to prove it to yourself that the base case is correct and that the recursive case is correct. that is all.

then it is guaranteed to work in however convoluted way it does, and the whole point of it is for us to not care about how it does it exactly, i.e. about its exact sequence of steps.

---

so *specifically* in your case, *assuming* `mergesort` indeed does work correctly (wait, *what?* never mind, suspend your disbelief for a moment),

```
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])
```

calls the function `mergesort` with the first half of `lst`, from its start to its midpoint, and stores the result - which is the *sorted* first half, *by assumption*, - in the variable `left`; then

```
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:])
```

calls the function `mergesort` with the *second* half of `lst`, from its midpoint to its end, and stores the result - which is the *sorted* second half, *by assumption*, - in the variable `right`;

and then you need to convince yourself that the rest of the code creates `newlist` from those two sorted halves such that `newlist` is *also* *sorted* in the correct order.

And then by the principle of mathematical induction this proves the correctness of  `mergesort`.

By assuming it works, we prove that it indeed works! Where's the catch? There's no catch, because the two cases that worked by assumption are for two *smaller* inputs (and that is our *recursive* case).

And when we divide a thing into two parts, over and over, eventually we're left with either a singleton, or an empty thing. And those two are *naturally* sorted (and that is our base case).

Recursion is a leap of faith. Assume the thing is working, then you get to use it. And if you use it correctly, you will have thus built the very thing you were using in the first place!

Comment: i, too, am a copy trying to call home to my creator. just gotta figure out the answer first...

Comment: you know, when I wrote that thing, that was the exact thing that popped into my head. (not before) :) :) :)

Comment: then there's this strange idea of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return which apparently was understood literally, by some.... and our OP is also asking about "returning".... strange confluence.

Comment: thank you for sharing, Will. i think about this stuff _all_ the time, so it's nice to be connected to others that are trying to understand it.